# Solve the system $3^x-2^{y^2}=77$, $3^{\frac{x}{3}}-2^{\frac{y^2}{2}}=7$ in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I had to solve the similar system $3^x-2^{y^2}=77,\; 3^{\frac{x}{2}}-2^{\frac{y^2}{2}}=7$ before, which can be solved like this:
$$3^{\frac{x}{2}}-2^{\frac{y^2}{2}}=7 \implies 2^{\frac{y^2}{2}}=3^{\frac{x}{2}}-7$$
$$2^{\frac{y^2}{2}}=3^{\frac{x}{2}}-7 \implies 2^{y^2}=(3^{\frac{x}{2}}-7)^2$$
$$2^{y^2}=(3^{\frac{x}{2}}-7)^2 \implies 2^{y^2}=3^{x}-14\cdot3^{\frac{x}{2}}+49$$

So putting that in the first equation:
$$3^x-2^{y^2}=77 \implies 3^x-3^{x}+14\cdot3^{\frac{x}{2}}-49=77$$
$$\mathbf{3^x-3^{x}+14\cdot3^{\frac{x}{2}}-49=77 \implies 14\cdot3^{\frac{x}{2}}=126}$$
$$14\cdot3^{\frac{x}{2}}=126 \implies 3^{\frac{x}{2}}=9$$
$$3^{\frac{x}{2}}=9 \implies x = 4$$

And putting the value of $x$ in the second equation we get $y$:
$$3^{\frac{x}{2}}-2^{\frac{y^2}{2}}=7 \implies 3^{2}-2^{\frac{y^2}{2}}=7$$
$$3^{2}-2^{\frac{y^2}{2}}=7 \implies 2^{\frac{y^2}{2}}=2$$
$$2^{\frac{y^2}{2}}=2 \implies y^2 = 2$$
$$y^2 = 2 \implies y = \sqrt{2}$$

So I tried solving the system in the question title with the same strategy until the step in bold, which gave me $3^x - 3^{\frac{2x}{3}}+14\cdot3^{\frac{x}{3}}=126$, and I have no idea how to progress further.

Comment: The system is of the form $\,a-b=7, a^3-b^2=77\,$ so in the end you get a [cubic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation) equation, which can be solved in radicals though the calculations are not necessarily pretty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $u=3^{\frac x 2}$ and $v=2^{\frac {y^2}2}$ then
$$\left \{
\begin{split}
u^3-v^2&=77\\
u-v&=7
\end{split}
\right.$$
So $v=u-7$ and thus $u^3-u^2+14u-126=0$.

Solving the latter [gives you](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20x%5E3-x%5E2%2B14x-126%3D0) 3 roots (1 real and 2 complex), and you can find $u$ and $v$, and get back to $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Am I doing it wrong or does it give some really ugly numbers?

Comment: No you are right, it looks pretty ugly.

Comment: For what it's worth, [this section of the Wikipedia Cubics article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#General_cubic_formula) plus a calculator will provide a very accurate approximation, within a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Using the hyperbolic method when there is only one real root as for$$u^3-u^2+14u-126=0$$ the solution is not ugly at all. It write
$$u=\frac{1}{3} \left(1+2 \sqrt{41} \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{1639}{41 \sqrt{41}}\right)\right)\right)$$ while using Cardano method, it write
$$\frac{1}{3} \left(1-\frac{41}{\sqrt[3]{1639+3 \sqrt{306138}}}+\sqrt[3]{1639+3
   \sqrt{306138}}\right)$$

Which one do you prefer ?